# AWS redirect traffic to high priority stacks

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

Need help in below scenario on aws

i have 2 stacks with different names with different priority EX (1 and 100), but same context path.
by default the traffic routes to stack which has priority 1 , but i want to test the stack which is of high priority.

EX : i use the alb url to test the stack

```
curl --request GET -v  --header "Content-type: application/json" https://alb/<context path> --insecure
```

can anyone help how can i get a traffic redirected to the second stack, tried adding host header in the listerner rule but not sure how to frame the curl command

```
curl --request GET -v  --header "Content-type: application/json" --header "Host: api.sample.com" "https://alb/<context path>" --insecure
```

Rules :

- stack 1 : path pattern /test/test1 forwarded to stack1
- stack 2 : path pattern /test/test1 & Host header api.sample.com forwarded to stack2.

regards,
vishal

Comment: Can you elaborate on what a 'stack' is in this context?

Comment: `--header "Host: api.sample.com"` is correct.  If your rules are in the order shown, however, the second rule would never be tested.  They're evaluated in listed order and the first matching rule is followed.

Comment: Is there any command where I can hit the high priority stack without disturbing the stack 1 as it will be live in all the environments and on different version

Comment: @user1190615 - can you show your rules page's screenshot or rule'ss dump in a json ?

Answer (score 0):

New host based routing feature in [AWS ALB](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-host-based-routing-support-for-aws-application-load-balancers/) fits properly for your use-case. Using this approach, you can configure routing rules to different [Target Groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-target-groups.html) based on the host from which you receive the request.

Hope this helps.